# local ssl cert on private ip on apache (linux)

Tags: linux, ssl, apache-2.4, raspbian

I've got a weird problem I can't seem to find an answer to.

I'm developing a webapp on Apache hosted on a Raspberry Pi and I'm having some trouble.

The Details:

1. The system I'm building is an "Offline" System. I.e the raspberry pi will not have access to the internet, and clients will connect to the raspberry pi via an access point using using the Pi's private IP.
2. Almost everything in the application works correctly offline, but I am having an issue where one function doesn't work because Chrome will not allow camera access by a site without SSL.

I have tried to follow a couple guides on how to create and use a self signed cert, but they all seem to involve using a domain name, instead of an IP, and if they do use an IP they use the public IP and not a local one.

Could anyone steer me in the right direction? Is there a better way to this then worrying about a Cert? or is there something special you have to do for the private IP if it is even possible?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? You should have been able to use the tutorial you found to create a self signed certificate for your IP address. Be specific.

Comment: The issue is, after following the guide, generating the CSR and applying it, I still cannot go the https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx without getting the insecure page error